# Redirecting from one php file to another php with Post parameters

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, post

I am calling a php file android app to upload two images to the server . now I have changed the server to amazon server . So i created a new php file to upload the images to amazon server. The problem is I need to redirect the calling php file into the new amazon php .

my old php file is

```
$namee=$_POST["name"];
$txnyear=$_POST["txn_year"];
$image=$_POST["image"];

$image2=$_POST["image2"];
$ID=$_POST["id"];
$decodedimage = base64_decode("$image");
$decodedimage2 = base64_decode("$image2");
$f = finfo_open();
$mime_type = finfo_buffer($f, $decodedimage, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$file_content=file_put_contents("/var/www/xxxx/CRM/CUST_IDS/".$namee.".png", $decodedimage); 
$file_content2=file_put_contents("/var/www/xxxx/CRM/CUST_PHOTO/".$namee.".png", $decodedimage2); 
if(!($decodedimage==null && $decodedimage2==null))
    }
```

So please help me to redirect This old php to new php with passsing this parameters .. thanks in advance .!

Answer (score 0):

You can use include to call old file from new php file

```
  include 'old.php';
```